# Solved: In graphene-django, how do i return an errors list?

Tags: graphene-django

Can i raise an exception in a `graphene.Mutation`'s `mutate` method so it gives an `"errors"` list in the GraphQL response?

This used to work in graphene-django 3.0.0b7:

```
class DeleteOrderlineMutation(graphene.Mutation):
    Output = graphene.ID()

    class Arguments:
        id = graphene.UUID()
        order_id = graphene.ID()

    @classmethod
    def mutate(cls, root, info, id, order_id):
        user = info.context.user
        order = Order.objects.for_user(user).get(pk=order_id)
        if not order.is_editable_by(user):
            raise GraphQLError(
                "Order mutation not allowed, Orderline can not be deleted."
            )
```

This would result in a response like this:

```
{
  ...
  "errors": [
      {"message": "Order mutation not allowed, Orderline can not be deleted.", ...}
  ]
}
```

However, in the latest 3.0.0, this gives

```
{
  'data': {
    'deleteOrderline': "<Promise at 0x7f899900d5b0 rejected with GraphQLError('Order mutation not allowed, Orderline can not be deleted.')>"
  }
}
```

I've searched the latest docs (https://docs.graphene-python.org/projects/django/en/latest/) on hints on how to return errors, but i didn't find anything.

I've bisected the tags, and it stopped working in 3.0.0b8. The changelog (https://github.com/graphql-python/graphene-django/releases/tag/v3.0.0b8) doesn't list anything that instantly sounds related to this.

In the commits between tags b7 and b8 (https://github.com/graphql-python/graphene-django/compare/v3.0.0b7..v3.0.0b8), all i found that looks related was the change to use `.formatted` instead of `format_error` (https://github.com/graphql-python/graphene-django/pull/1327), as it's in an `except` for the GraphQLError, but i'm not sure.

What is the proper way to get an errors list in the GraphQL response? Can it be done by raising an exception, or do we need to do it differently?

Edit: I'm currently looking into the method outlined in [Graphene errors messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57807244/graphene-errors-messages): Define an ErrorType class and add it to the mutation definition.

Edit 2: Solved. It's a bug in graphene-django, workaround is outlined in https://github.com/graphql-python/graphene-django/issues/1367